# How to verify a US based company?

Tags: legal, usa

I have been recently hired by a US based company to code on their platform.
Living in a different country, how can I verify that the company is legit and how do I find any information regarding the company.
Like in my country the government has a portal where I can check the registration details of the company including the registered office address, board members, paid up capital etc.
I have requested the registration information of the company and they have provided me with the registration file number.
But I cant find an official site, where I can cross verify them.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you happen to know which US State the company resides in?

Comment: yes, State of Delaware

Answer (score 2):

To verify a US corporation, limited liability company or similar, check with the Secretary of State for the state in which the business is registered.  Most of them will have a "Business Portal" link where you can get this sort of information.

If the company is not incorporated or have a similar legal status, then check the business license department in the city that the business is in.